# short way should respond_to(:attribute) rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a bunch attributes for my model post in my rspec test:

```
it { should respond_to(:title) }
it { should respond_to(:description) }
it { should respond_to(:instruction) }
.
.
.
```

**Can I be more precise, use less lines in the test something like:**

```
it { should respond_to(:title, :description, :instruction) }
```

Comment: Why are you using respond_to instead of directly testing the attributes? `its(:title) { should == 'blahblah' }`

Comment: Thank you @Beerlington I have fixed with `it { should have_fields(:email, :login) }` I am using mongoid. You can see in https://github.com/evansagge/mongoid-rspec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is in https://github.com/evansagge/mongoid-rspec :

```
it { should have_fields(:title, :description, :instruction) }
```

Thank you @Beerlington